# What is the use of fd (file descriptor) in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

```js
    fs.open('input.txt', 'r+', function(err, fd) {
       console.log(fd);
       if (err) {
           return console.error(err);
       }
    })
```

What is `fd` here, and why is it giving 3 when I print it using `console.log();`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

File descriptors are a concept used in many programming languages, they represent a reference to an opened file.

The file descriptor will be used to reference the correct file stream by all file system related functions.

In fact stdout, stdin and stderr get assigned a file descriptor too, they are occupying fd `0` through `2`, the next free file descriptor value is 3. Thats why the value returned in your example is `3`.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) for more background information.

Answer (score 11):

In your example, `fd` is the second parameter of the `callback` passed to `fs.open`:

- What is important is that is the second parameter.
- Its name is not important.

That second parameter represents a **file descriptor**, useful to access that opened file inside the callback.

For example <sup>1</sup>:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var fileName = "foo.txt";

fs.exists(fileName, function(exists) {
  if (exists) {
    // get information about the file
    fs.stat(fileName, function(error, stats) {
      // open the file (getting a file descriptor to it)
      fs.open(fileName, "r", function(error, fd) {
        var buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);

        // read its contents into buffer
        fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(error, bytesRead, buffer) {
          var data = buffer.toString("utf8", 0, buffer.length);

          console.log(data);
          fs.close(fd);
        });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

there, you have `fd` (the second parameter of `fs.open`) passed to `fs.read` as its first parameter, and so you can read that file.

---

<sup>1: Example taken from:   http://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-the-file-system-in-node-js/</sup>

Comment: [From the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback): "Using fs.exists() to check for the existence of a file before calling fs.open(), fs.readFile() or fs.writeFile() is **not recommended**. Doing so introduces a race condition, since other processes may change the file's state between the two calls. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file does not exist."
Also says that fs.exists() is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

One crucial information of note is that `fd` can used for both reading and writing at the same time. That is, essentially the use case of calling `fs.open()`. It is useful if you want to perform several actions on the opened file.

Here is an example.

```
fs.open('<directory>', 'r+', (err, fd) =>  {
// r+ is the flag that tells fd to open it in read + write mode.
// list of all system flags: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags
// read using fd:https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback
// write using fd: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback
// close the flag: fs.close(fd);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think from the concept of c. A file is assigned a number which assign a reference to a file location so fd helps within the underlying code to locate the current file been worked on.